# Avoid duplicates while adding to linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to prevent duplicate while adding to my linked list. Any thought will help please. I want to first lookup the list. If the item is already in the list don't add.I've tried so many thing but nothing is working. I'm posting my add method. This is working but it's accepting duplicate.

```
public void addNumber(MyNumber numb) {
        NumberNode previous;
        NumberNode current;
        if (head == null) {
            head = new NumberNode(numb, null);
        } else {
            previous = head;
            current = head;

            while (current != null
                    && current.getData().compareTo(numb) <= 0) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.getLink();

            }
            if (head == current) {
                head = new NumberNode(numb, current);

            } else {
                previous.setLink(new NumberNode(numb, current));

            }

        }

        numberOfNumber++;
        System.out.println(numb);


    }
```

Comment: A list without duplicates is btw called a "Set". Also: Is your list sorted? Then finding the insertion point like you already do and compare to the current value already tells you if you have a duplicate.

Comment: I think it would help if you showed us the code for your `NumberNode` and `MyNumber` classes.

Comment: can I inbox you the code via email please?